# Any pros and cons of the Cardano's method to solve cubic?

Tags: cubics

Cardano's method can be used to solve all arbitrary cubic equations. However, I doubt this method would be flawless and I am curious what limitations does the Cardano's method have.  So far I only know about the Casus irreducible cases.

Thank you.